# Where to add compiler options like -ea in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to add the `-ea` option. I set it in `Project Settings` --> `Compiler` --> `Java Compiler` : `Additional command line parameters`.

But it caused a make error: `invalid flag: -ea`.
P.S.: the above error message may not be the same as yours, because IntelliJ showed error in my native language, not English. I translated it into English.

Comment: -ea  (enable assertions). Assertions are disabled by default in Oracle HotSpot

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The `-ea` option to enable assertions is passed to the JVM not to the compiler. Add it as a VM option for your runtime configuration.

Specific location in the menu: *Run > Edit Configurations... > Configuration > VM options*:

[image: Where to put the <code>-ea</code> flag]

Comment: can this configuration be modified during unit tests started with gradle for example?

Comment: Don't forget to hit save icon after adding -ea.

Comment: In my specific case (`assert` commands to enable in the middle of some Kotlin code), I had to `Add new` configuration first, and then select `Kotlin`. After that, I could see some form showing the `VM Options` field as suggested here, in which to add the `-ea` option.

Answer (score 10):

You can also make IntelliJ IDEA support assertions by default by changing the default Application configuration:

In the top menu, press *Run > Edit Configurations > Defaults > Application > VM options*.

To enable the assertion feature for all application, you could just fill the `VM options` with `-ea`

Comment: By "Defaults", do you mean "Templates"?

Comment: @jduan, Yes, kind of. When you set the VM options like above, every time you add configuration, assertion feature is enabled by default

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same thing as the accepted answer?

Comment: Is there a way to enable assertions to any debug build to all developers - maybe using a Gradle property?

Comment: What is "Defaults?" There is no such item in the run configurations list pane. Nor is there "Templates."

In fact there isn't even "Edit configurations" just "Run configurations."

Answer (score 9):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3:

- Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Modify options -> Add VM options.
- Input `-ea` then click OK button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Override compiler parameters per-module -> +

Your project name is module name. And add `-ea` to the `Compilation options` for `javac`

It works for IDEA 2021.2, Fedora linux x86_64, OpenJDK  1.8 64bit