# assert keyword(cannot resolve symbol assert)

Tags: java, assert

```
   GridBlock firstBlock =grid.getEntranceBlock(); //enter through entrance
        assert(firstBlock!=null);
```

The above assert keyword is flaged by the IDEA and I don't understand why. If i try to compile i get an warning "Warning:(83, 25) java: as of release 1.4, 'assert' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
  (use -source 1.4 or higher to use 'assert' as a keyword)". As I understand you can use assert without having to import anything. Now i don't understand what I am missing. I tried download new JDK but it didn't help. I m using Intellij

Comment: You are missing `-ea` option, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168257/where-to-add-compiler-options-like-ea-in-intellij-idea).

Comment: Can you share the surrounding code? My guess is that you have a syntax error somewhere above that line.

Comment: I retract my comment, did not realize that it was a warning. So you are compiling with version < 1.4 ?

Comment: You did not put the `assert` in a declaration part of the class, did you?

Comment: I did. Well I managed to fix it. In Intellij, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S , then under "Project Language Level" choose a version higher than 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Check what "language level" your project is using: File > Project Structure > Project > Project language level

You might be on a very old level for some reason. If there's no reason to be on it, just try increasing it to something more modern -- this will also give you other very useful language features.