# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after assert statement

Tags: java, string, assert

I have a `String` array `tmp` got by `String[] tmp = line.split(",");`

Then,

I got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` on code

```
assert tmp.length == 4;
int r = Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]);   ----error line
```

and `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` on code

```
assert tmp.length == 3;
String name = tmp[2];    -----error line
```

I do not think this error is reasonable. The assert statement passes correctly and how can a array with `.length=4` having no element indexed `3`? Could anyone tell me why...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Have you activated the `assert` option with `-ea`?

Comment: @Nikolas I have just read this post before I asked. The most important part is different, which is that I have the `assert`

Comment: Did you add `-enableassertions` or `-ea` as VM arguments ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj OH...is there a choice? I thought it is always activated

Comment: @Litchy Nope it is deactivated by default. If you use Eclipse you can look at the following post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise

Comment: @YassinHajaj thanks! I think this is exactly my issue

Comment: Don't use asserts for input validation.

Comment: @Litchy Alright I'll add an answer to help future users encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem here is that you did not activate the assertions in the JVM options

In command line `java MyProgram -ea`

For Eclipse, see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11415579/5050667)** answer.

For IntelliJ, see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18168305/5050667)** answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, assertions are disabled and you should enable them using either of below command-line switches:

- `-ea`
- `-enableassertions`

You can check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/assert-4/index.html) for more package and sub-package finer grained activation.

For arguments or variables validation, you should use a dedicated *Assertion* library or simply craft yours.

A lightweight and fluent one should be the [*valid4j*](http://www.valid4j.org):

```
//...
Assertive.ensure(tmp.length == 4, "The split result array must have 4 elements: (%d)", tmp.length);
```