# How to enable assertions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, assertion

I've created sample class to test assertions in Kotlin

```
class Assertion {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        assert(a > 0 && b > 0)
        return a + b
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Assertion().sum(-1, 2)
}
```

and was using the following options but the program doesn't throw assert exception.

`-ea:AssertionKt`, `-ea:Assertion` and `-ea:...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enable assertions in Kotlin, run the JVM with the `-ea` option, without any additional specifiers.

Comment: clear. thx. I also found useful [thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-like-assert-statement/2277) related to this topic

Comment: @Maxim please, accept the answer if it solves your issue ;)

Comment: All of the answers on this topic are uniform in the sentence like "run the JVM with the `-ea` option", however I cannot find how to actually do that in Android Studio. Googling "kotlin android studio set jvm option" or similar yields no solution.
EDIT: After a while of question rephrasing I found the solution, if anyone will be wondering the same [Where to add compiler options like -ea in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168257/where-to-add-compiler-options-like-ea-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: `kotlinc -J-ea` from https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-i-use-asserts-in-kotlin-scripts/4110/3

Answer (score 6):

In `Kotlin`, unlike `Java`, assertions can be enabled/disabled only on top-level, i.e. by specifying `-ea` option to JVM.

Behind the scenes, `assert()` in Kotlin is a function, defined in `AssertionsJVM.kt` file. `ENABLED` variable in the `_Assertions` object is used to determine if assertions are enabled.

```
@PublishedApi
internal object _Assertions {
    @JvmField @PublishedApi
    internal val ENABLED: Boolean = javaClass.desiredAssertionStatus()
}
```

The `ENABLED` variable is assign to `true` if assertions enabled for the `_Assertions` class.

As a consequence, to turn on asserts in Kotlin they have to be enabled in JVM for

- all classes `-ea`
- or one particular class `-ea:kotlin._Assertions`