# Assert the String has certain length (Java)

Tags: java, string, assert

Is there any way to assert in a method that input String has certain length?

I tried assert `stringName[4];` but seems like it doesn't work

Comment: `assert stringName.length() == 4;` perhaps? (That's assuming you're using Java's built-in assertions.)

Comment: Please share your test case and the piece of code you are trying to test

Comment: Possible duplicate [What does the “assert” keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018683/what-does-the-assert-keyword-do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to use the Java's `assert` keyword and not any library like JUnit, then you can probably use:

```
String myStr = "hello";
assert myStr.length() == 5 : "String length is incorrect";
```

From the official docs:

> The assertion statement has two forms. The first, simpler form is:
>
> `assert Expression1;`
>
> where Expression1 is a boolean expression. When
>   the system runs the assertion, it evaluates `Expression1` and if it is
>   false throws an `AssertionError` with no detail message.
>
> The second form of the assertion statement is:
>
> `assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;`
>
> where:
>   `Expression1` is a boolean expression. `Expression2` is an expression that
>   has a value. (It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared
>   void.)

You can use the following if you're using a testing library like JUnit:

```
String myStr = "hello";
assertEquals(5, myStr.length());
```

Update:
As correctly pointed out in the comments by AxelH, after compilation, you run the first solution as `java -ea AssertionTest`. The -ea flag enables assertions.

Comment: @AxelH I wouldn't let any assert statement run in a production environment, either.

Comment: so if the length is not 5, it throws you message saying "String length is incorrect"? I tried this but doesn't show up in console - can you possibly think why it's not showing up?

Comment: @Miervatea did you put in the `-ea ` when running as I've mentioned at the end of the answer?

Comment: public class practice{ 
 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  String s1 = "hello";
  assert s1.length() == 5  : "incorrect length of String";
 }}

it's terminating itself before I type -ea thing - sorry it's very dumb : /

Comment: You don't need to enter -ea after running the program. If you're using an IDE like intellij, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168257/where-to-add-compiler-options-like-ea-in-intellij-idea can probably help you with entering the flag. If you're running the program from a terminal/cmd prompt, instead of running `java Practice` run `java -ea Practice`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) [`hasSize()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractCharSequenceAssert.html#hasSize(int)):

```java
assertThat(stringName).hasSize(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `assert`, I'd recommend using `Exception` to check the state of the variables as a simple demo:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
if (arr.length != 4) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Array length is not expected");
}
```

This will directly give the **hint** by exceptions and you don't need to bother with `assert` in jvm options.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Array length is not expected
    at basic.AssertListLength.main(AssertListLength.java:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hamcrest, then you can do:

```
 assertThat("text", hasLength(4))
```

See http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/ > CharSequenceLength

Good thing about this is that it will have a proper error message, among others including the string itself.